# how to get value in javascript for asp Label control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Suppose I have asp Lable set in markup like:

```
<asp:Label ID="myID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

then set value for this Label in code behind like:

```
myID.Text =100
```

then I want get the value 100 in javascript. I tried:

```
document.getElementById('<%=myID.ClientID%>').value;
```

but is not working. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that labels render as spans.  Try getting the inner text.

```
document.getElementById('<%=myID.ClientID%>').innerText;
```

Comment: Ah, try switching to `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you need to use the html property.

```
var g = $('#<%=myID.ClientID%>').html();
```

These will NOT work with jquery

- $('#<%=myID.ClientID%>').innerText
- $('#<%=myID.ClientID%>').innerHTML
- $('#<%=myID.ClientID%>').val()

Answer (score -2):

```
var label=$("#<%myID.ClientID%>").html();
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.